# How to get daily mindful time from HealthKit?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I'm trying to calculate how many mindful minutes the user had during the day, so I tried to do this:

```
func getDailyMindfulnessTime(completion: @escaping (TimeInterval) -> Void) {
    let sampleType = HKSampleType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .mindfulSession)!
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)
    let startDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)

    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: predicate, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (_, results, error) in
        if error != nil {
            fatalError("*** HealthKit returned error while trying to query today's mindful sessions. The error was: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        var totalTime = TimeInterval()
        if let results = results {
            for result in results {
                totalTime += result.endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
            }
        } else {
            completion(0)
        }
    }
    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

then:

```
    healthStore.getDailyMindfulnessTime { (result) in
        self.meditationTodayMinutesLabel.text = "\(result) minutes today"
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. In fact, the label's text doesn't change from what I set it to in Interface Builder. I've used this kind of pattern for other HealthKit data like daily step count, but I don't know why this has no effect.

EDIT: NEVERMIND, it was a really stupid error, I should've put `completion(totalTime)` after the for-in loop. OOPS

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: the label just doesn't change it's text

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint at `self.meditationTodayMinutesLabel.text`, does it get executed?

Comment: no breakpoint... but it seems that the completion handler never gets executed, since the label is not changing and if i put a print statement in there it doesn't get executed

Answer (score 1):

NEVERMIND, it was a really stupid error, I should've put completion(totalTime) after the for-in loop. OOPS